# Implementing partial response in cloud endpoints v2 - Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I created a simple API in cloud endpoints v2 using Java. I see there is one parameter with the name of **fields** in the API Explorer for partial response. But
this is not working for me.

I saw YouTube API which is using this. How can I implement it in my own API?
I'm not able to find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is explicitly called out as an [excluded feature of Endpoints 2.0 Java](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating) right now.

Here's an excerpt from that page for posterity:

> **Currently excluded features and tools**
>
> ...
>
> - `fields` partial responses

However, the page does suggest submitting a feature request using [the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues) if it is something that you would like to see in Endpoints.